# Load images onchange of select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select list:

```
<select id="boy" class="list">
    <option value="">Boy picture...</option>
    <option value="1" >Picture 1</option>
    <option value="2" >Picture 2</option>
    <option value="3" >Picture 3</option>
    <option value="4" >Picture 4</option>
</select>
<select id="girl" class="list">
    <option value="">Girl picture.... </option>
    <option value="a">Picture 1</option>
    <option value="b">Picture 2</option>
    <option value="c">Picture 3</option>
    <option value="d">Picture 4</option>
</select>
```

and would like to load picture with both select list in separate div tag. 
When I click on `Picture 1` in `boy` list I want to load boy picture, and when clik on `Picture 1` in `girl` list I want to load girl picture... 
And, when `Picture 1` is loaded and when press `Next` button Picture 2 to load..and so on.

I do not know how to do that.

My [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/RsgBn/)

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Question is How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to attach an image to every option of the select and than show the image when the option is selected.

To do so I set a custom attribute on the options `myImg` with the value of the image of boys and girls, I use random images (it takes a while to get them).

```
<select id="boy" class="list">
    <option value="">Boy picture...</option>
    <option value="1" myImg="http://randomimage.setgetgo.com/get.php?height=50&width=50">Picture 1</option>
    <option value="2"  myImg="http://randomimage.setgetgo.com/get.php?height=50&width=50">Picture 2</option>
    <option value="3"  myImg="http://randomimage.setgetgo.com/get.php?height=50&width=50">Picture 3</option>
    <option value="4"  myImg="http://randomimage.setgetgo.com/get.php?height=50&width=50">Picture 4</option>
</select>
```

In the [`change event`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) I get the attribute with `$('option:selected', this).attr('myImg')` and set the css `background-image` of the picture div:

```
$('#boy').on('change', function () {
    $('select').removeClass('activeList');
    $(this).addClass('activeList');
    $(".picture").css('background-image', 'url(' + $('option:selected', this).attr('myImg') + ')');
});
$('#girl').on('change', function () {
    $('select').removeClass('activeList');
    $(this).addClass('activeList');
    $(".picture").css('background-image', 'url(' + $('option:selected', this).attr('myImg') + ')');
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/LT8zc/

If I don't understand the question I enjoyed to develop this :-)

### EDIT

If you want so set no-repeat on image set it like:

```
$(".picture").css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + $('option:selected', this).attr('myImg') + ')',
    'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'
});
```

or define it as regular css rule (not set via jQuery)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/LT8zc/1/

Comment: How to set the background does not repeat?

Comment: By setting no-repeat as css option, see http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/LT8zc/1/

Comment: @Timberman have you solved? If so consider to accept it: stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer